# Blood Bowl 2nd edition: Star Players

Tags: blood-bowl

Is there a list of Star Players for 2nd Edition of Blood Bowl somewhere? Obviously the ones from Star Players Handbook and Companion Rulebook is simple enough but the ones printed in White Dwarf etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Games Workshop is incredibly protective about their IP, so it can be hard to find stuff like this.

That said, I found a thread [here](http://www.talkfantasyfootball.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=28881) that tries to collate the list of star players.

Here's the list they've compiled:

**Star Players**

- Axebreaker Jones
- Asperon Thorn
- Barik Farblast
- Dieter Hammerlash
- Dirty Dan
- Duke Luthor Von Hawkfire
- Eldril Sidewinder
- Ernald Spirtburner
- Frank N. Stein
- Garbage Throttlesnot
- Granite Rivalblade
- Greaser Geargrinder
- Griff Oberwald
- Grimwold Grimbreath
- Hak Demoncutter
- Harg Vainkill
- Hawthorn Tullaris
- Highelm Lyrpadre
- Hoshi Komi
- Hubris Rakarth
- Ibrahim Golddawn
- Jacob Von Altdorf
- Krug Painspear
- Moravis Curfew
- Morg'th N'hthrog
- Odium Khan
- 'Pick' Seamsunder
- Pierrot Rainforest
- Puggy Baconbreath
- Ramtut III
- Rasta Tailspike
- Rip Sorepain
- Ritter Von Baum
- Slarga Fourstrike
- Soaren Hightower
- Split Tendoncutter
- Stuka Schmidtt
- 'Surehanded' Gregor Meissen
- Tuern Redvenom
- Urfrik Skillhack
- Valen Swift
- Varag Ghoul-chewer
- Warmglow Vindaloo
- Wilhelm Chaney
- Withergrasp Doubledrool
- Wormhowl Greyscar
- Ziggi Abschuss
- Zug

**Companion**

- Bardin Ironglove
- Bellow Thunderslam
- 'Big' Gunn Schonn
- Bilerot Vomitflesh
- Borg'th N'hthrog
- Dolfar Longstride
- Dorjak Sureclaw
- Eoarn Harkon
- Flint Churnblade
- Galmen Goreblade
- Gorflem Rot-breath
- Grak'ng'grak Gorthag
- Grograt Crunchskull
- Jordell Freshbreeze
- Kolath Head-ripper
- Lewdgrip Whiparm
- Luarn Proudbow
- M'gorg'gn'throg
- Petro D'Arvill
- Siggi 'The Boot' Schuster
- Spiky Norman
- Ugroth 'Ripper' Bolgrot

They sure printed a lot -- hope that helps.